# Get All music files path from device in Android?

Tags: android

I am using below provided code to list all songs from my device in the Arraylist variable "al".Then from that list i am selecting path of my desired song and then i am using that particular song path to set it as phone ringtone.Also the code that i have used to set phone ringtone, i have given below.But the problem is that, After assigning phone ringtone when i am again trying to list all the songs using same code then the song that i have set as Phone ringtone previously is not listing in my ArrayList variable "al".

//Code to list all songs path

```
ArrayList<String> al;
ArrayList<String> alname;
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_select);
    al=new ArrayList<String>();
    alname=new ArrayList<String>();
    getAllSongsFromSDCARD();


}
public void getAllSongsFromSDCARD() 
{
    String[] STAR = { "*" };        
    Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(allsongsuri, STAR, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String song_name = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                al.add(fullpath);

                String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                alname.add(song_name);
                int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));



            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

// code to set Phone Ringtone

```
File newSoundFile = new File(al.get(0));

                                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "aa");
                                        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
                                        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
                                        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                                        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
                                        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                                        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
                                        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                                        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                                        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                        AssignToAllActivity.this.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                                        Uri newUri = AssignToAllActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                                        try {
                                            getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA 
                                                    + "=\"" + newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                                            RingtoneManager  manager = new RingtoneManager(AssignToAllActivity.this);
                                            manager.setStopPreviousRingtone(true);
                                            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(AssignToAllActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                                           Toast.makeText(AssignToAllActivity.this,"setAsRingTuneSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e) {
                                               Toast.makeText(AssignToAllActivity.this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code does not find the song in the second run because your code deletes it.

```
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA 
                                                + "=\"" + newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
```

Comment: Sir If i am removing that line then it is not setting that song as Phone ringtone.Please tell me is there any other way to achieve this or any modification in my existing code.

Comment: i donot know how to set ringtones. your question was : **why did my song disappear.** maybe you can save the file under a different filename and use that copy as ringtone.